# How to access the Docker Container Hosted on Windows machine

Tags: docker, docker-machine

I run the docker container using below command

`docker run -p 9595:9595 --name sample-docker-ad --restart always -itd microsoft/dotnet-samples:aspnetapp`

It runs well and I can see the output as below

```
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> docker ps
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                                COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                    NAMES
b466a12d025f        microsoft/dotnet-samples:aspnetapp   "dotnet aspnetapp.dll"   10 seconds ago      Up 4 seconds        0.0.0.0:9595->9595/tcp   sample-docker-ad
```

I confirm its port using

```
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> docker port b466a12d025f
9595/tcp -> 0.0.0.0:9595
```

My docker-machine configuration is as below

```
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> docker-machine env
$Env:DOCKER_TLS_VERIFY = "1"
$Env:DOCKER_HOST = "tcp://192.168.0.101:2376"
$Env:DOCKER_CERT_PATH = "C:\Users\hp\.docker\machine\machines\default"
$Env:DOCKER_MACHINE_NAME = "default"
$Env:COMPOSE_CONVERT_WINDOWS_PATHS = "true"
# Run this command to configure your shell:
# & "C:\Program Files\Docker\Docker\Resources\bin\docker-machine.exe" env | Invoke-Expression
```

I have also tried

```
 PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> docker exec b466a12d025f ipconfig

Windows IP Configuration


Ethernet adapter Ethernet:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::9de4:d87:f620:26f9%4
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 172.30.245.64
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.240.0
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 172.30.240.1
```

I am trying to access the application using `192.168.0.101:9595` and `172.30.245.64:9595`

I am getting This site can't be reached.

I am able to access the application using `172.30.245.64` without port.
Not sure if its a correct way to doing it

Please suggest the changes as per the standards

Comment: Possible duplicate of: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43769806/docker-desktop-for-windows-cannot-access-service-on-exposed-port-in-windows-con

Comment: Yes, I have already tried it. It's Not working. Also tried using the IP Still the same.

Comment: did you try with curl or postman to see if the error is related to the app itself?

Comment: @Flo: I have tried with the postman and curl also still it's not working.

Comment: Try with another port on the host machine like `-p 9594:9595`

Comment: @Flo : Tried that.Not Working, Also One thing is sure there is not a problem with the Image or the container Because I also try to deploy and Access NGINX Image