# Docker compose - Service can't access mongoDB in the same network: Connection refused

Tags: mongodb, spring-boot, docker, kotlin, docker-compose

I know there's a lot of similar posts but none seem to solve my problem.

I have a Kotlin Spring Boot app and a mongoDB running in docker (Windows). The problem here is that seems that my app does not have connection to the mongoDB. It throws the error `Connection refused`, followed by `Exception in monitor thread while connecting to server localhost:27017`.

Although I am explicitly pointing to `mongodb` in the `application.properties` file:

**application.properties**

```
spring.data.mongodb.uri=mongodb://admin:admin@mongodb:27017/oasis
```

the mongodb seems to be ignored and it points to `localhost` instead. But if I start the application in the IDE of my local machine or I access the mongoDB from my local machine there's no problem.

I can see that the MongoClient generated for this connection has all the uri attributes right except the host:

```
MongoClient with metadata {"driver": {"name": "mongo-java-driver|sync|spring-boot", "version": "4.6.1"}, "os": {"type": "Linux", "name": "Linux", "architecture": "amd64", "version": "5.15.49-linuxkit"}, "platform": "Java/Oracle Corporation/17.0.2+8-86"} created with settings MongoClientSettings{readPreference=primary, writeConcern=WriteConcern{w=null, wTimeout=null ms, journal=null}, retryWrites=true, retryReads=true, readConcern=ReadConcern{level=null}, credential=MongoCredential{mechanism=null, userName='admin', source='oasis', password=<hidden>, mechanismProperties=<hidden>}, streamFactoryFactory=null, commandListeners=[io.micrometer.core.instrument.binder.mongodb.MongoMetricsCommandListener@353efdbf], codecRegistry=ProvidersCodecRegistry{codecProviders=[ValueCodecProvider{}, BsonValueCodecProvider{}, DBRefCodecProvider{}, DBObjectCodecProvider{}, DocumentCodecProvider{}, IterableCodecProvider{}, MapCodecProvider{}, GeoJsonCodecProvider{}, GridFSFileCodecProvider{}, Jsr310CodecProvider{}, JsonObjectCodecProvider{}, BsonCodecProvider{}, EnumCodecProvider{}, com.mongodb.Jep395RecordCodecProvider@4940809c]}, clusterSettings={hosts=[localhost:27017], srvServiceName=mongodb, mode=SINGLE, requiredClusterType=UNKNOWN, requiredReplicaSetName='null', serverSelector='null', clusterListeners='[]', serverSelectionTimeout='30000 ms', localThreshold='30000 ms'}, socketSettings=SocketSettings{connectTimeoutMS=10000, readTimeoutMS=0, receiveBufferSize=0, sendBufferSize=0}, heartbeatSocketSettings=SocketSettings{connectTimeoutMS=10000, readTimeoutMS=10000, receiveBufferSize=0, sendBufferSize=0}, connectionPoolSettings=ConnectionPoolSettings{maxSize=100, minSize=0, maxWaitTimeMS=120000, maxConnectionLifeTimeMS=0, maxConnectionIdleTimeMS=0, maintenanceInitialDelayMS=0, maintenanceFrequencyMS=60000, connectionPoolListeners=[io.micrometer.core.instrument.binder.mongodb.MongoMetricsConnectionPoolListener@55cff952], maxConnecting=2}, serverSettings=ServerSettings{heartbeatFrequencyMS=10000, minHeartbeatFrequencyMS=500, serverListeners='[]', serverMonitorListeners='[]'}, sslSettings=SslSettings{enabled=false, invalidHostNameAllowed=false, context=null}, applicationName='null', compressorList=[], uuidRepresentation=JAVA_LEGACY, serverApi=null, autoEncryptionSettings=null, contextProvider=null}
```

here's the full **error message** on my application startup:

```
2022-10-24 12:53:38.541  INFO 7 --- [localhost:27017] org.mongodb.driver.cluster               : Exception in monitor thread while connecting to server localhost:27017

com.mongodb.MongoSocketOpenException: Exception opening socket
        at com.mongodb.internal.connection.SocketStream.open(SocketStream.java:70) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.6.1.jar!/:na]
        at com.mongodb.internal.connection.InternalStreamConnection.open(InternalStreamConnection.java:180) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.6.1.jar!/:na]
        at com.mongodb.internal.connection.DefaultServerMonitor$ServerMonitorRunnable.lookupServerDescription(DefaultServerMonitor.java:193) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.6.1.jar!/:na]
        at com.mongodb.internal.connection.DefaultServerMonitor$ServerMonitorRunnable.run(DefaultServerMonitor.java:157) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.6.1.jar!/:na]
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833) ~[na:na]
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
        at java.base/sun.nio.ch.Net.pollConnect(Native Method) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/sun.nio.ch.Net.pollConnectNow(Net.java:672) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/sun.nio.ch.NioSocketImpl.timedFinishConnect(NioSocketImpl.java:542) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/sun.nio.ch.NioSocketImpl.connect(NioSocketImpl.java:597) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:327) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:633) ~[na:na]
        at com.mongodb.internal.connection.SocketStreamHelper.initialize(SocketStreamHelper.java:107) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.6.1.jar!/:na]
        at com.mongodb.internal.connection.SocketStream.initializeSocket(SocketStream.java:79) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.6.1.jar!/:na]
        at com.mongodb.internal.connection.SocketStream.open(SocketStream.java:65) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.6.1.jar!/:na]
        ... 4 common frames omitted
```

This is my **docker-compose.yml**:

```
version: "3.8"
services:
  mongodb:
    image: mongo:4.0.18
    restart: on-failure
    container_name: mongodb
    hostname: mongodb
    ports:
      - "27017:27017"
    environment:
      - MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME=$MONGO_ROOT_USERNAME
      - MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD=$MONGO_ROOT_PASSWORD
      - MONGO_INITDB_DATABASE=$MONGO_DB
      - MONGO_DB_USERNAME=$MONGO_DB_USERNAME
      - MONGO_DB_PASSWORD=$MONGO_DB_PASSWORD
    volumes:
      - ./infrastructure/local/mongodb/oasis/initdb.d/create-user.sh:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/create-user.sh:ro
      - mongodata:/data/db
  application:
    container_name: application
    hostname: application
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    restart: on-failure
    depends_on:
      - mongodb
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
    links:
      - mongodb
volumes:
  mongodata:
```

and that's how I'm setting the **mongoTemplate** in my application:

```
@Configuration
@Import(value = [MongoAutoConfiguration::class])
@EnableMongoRepositories(basePackageClasses = [
    ...
    (My repo classes)
    ...
])
class MongoDBConfig(
    val mongoClient: MongoClient
){
    @Bean
    @Throws(exceptionClasses = [Exception::class])
    fun mongoTemplate(): MongoTemplate {
        return MongoTemplate(mongoClient, "oasis")
    }
}
```

The only solution that partially worked for me is to set `network_mode: "host"`. With that config the application from inside the docker finally had connection to the mongodb, BUT I couldn't access my application endpoints from my local machine. Seems to be a known behaviour in Windows (official docs): `"The host networking driver only works on Linux hosts, and is not supported on Docker Desktop for Mac, Docker Desktop for Windows, or Docker EE for Windows Server."`

I've also tried setting up a custom network, link mongodb on the application docker compose description... All solutions I've seen on the interet. Nothing seems to work for me.

I'll be more than glad if someone gives me some clue of what I am doing wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I think the root cause of the problem is Windows and docker cooperability.

Check this solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43770786/5771474

For more details you can dig here: https://docs.docker.com/desktop/networking/